# How do I select elements in jQuery by using a variable for the ID in "Attribute Starts With Selector"

Tags: javascript, jquery

Instead of using :

```
$('input[id^="appName"]').each(function () {

            }  
        });
```

I would like to use a varibale for *Attribute Starts With Selector*

```
    var attrName = "appName";
    $('input[id^=attrName]').each(function () {

        }  
    });
```

The above syntax doesn't work. I checked the jQuery documentation and answers here without success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
 var attrName = "appName";
 $('input[id^=' + attrName + ']').each(function () {
      // do stuff here
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/156/